# Drag and Drop for Math Game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am having a hard time figuring out how to create a drag and drop feature in my app that will accept a draggable item and decide whether it is the correct answer and if it is correct it will display a message saying success!

My app displays two images. Both images are portions of a pizza pie, and then it will display 8 draggable numbers that you have to choose from and drag them into a droppable box which will check if it's correct. So I start with:

```
 PizzaImageOne[1]="http://s23.postimg.org/6yojml8vb/Pizza_One.png"
 PizzaImageOne[2]="http://s13.postimg.org/5d8zxnb2b/pizzatwo.png"
```

this happens 8 times so each number of the array represents how many slices it holds.

Then I call `var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));`. I store a random number into the variable `whichImage` which holds the number of pizza slices because each array number correlates with the pizza slices image which I will use to generate random pizzas by doing this:

```
document.write('<img src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'">');
```

I do that all over again with a new array

```
PizzaImageTwo[1]="http://s23.postimg.org/6yojml8vb/Pizza_One.png"
PizzaImageTwo[2]="http://s13.postimg.org/5d8zxnb2b/pizzatwo.png"
```

same exact thing but with new variables so the random call can be different than the first one

```
 var whichImage2 = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1))
```

Then I have

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable1" ).draggable();
    });
</script>
```

I do that 8 times so `#draggable1`, `#draggable2`, `#draggable3`,... all the way to 8.

I then made an array and saved them into each array like this 8 times each draggable function represents numbers from 1 to 8 because we are adding pizza pies like fractions.

```
var theimagestwo = new Array();
Draggablenumber[1] = $("#draggable1");
DraggableNumber[2] = $("#draggable2");
```

I do this until I fill up 8 draggable numbers in each array

So the logic is `MyAnswer = WhichImage + WhichImage2`. Then I have to check if `DraggableNumber[MyAnswer]` is dropped then I have the right answer...

How would I go about creating this feature?

Comment: can you help with an answer?

Comment: I am still trying to understand the question. It would be easier if you added a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/x1uzqsxe/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it, you can change the SVG to Canvas and clone in your Pizza image if you like.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/x1uzqsxe/5/

**HTML**

```
<div id="NewSlice">
  <p>Take a Slice</p>
  <div class="pieSlice draggable"></div>
</div>
<div id="MakePie">
  <p>
    Make Pie Here
  </p>
  <svg id="EmptyPie">
    <circle r="38" cx="75" cy="75" />
  </svg>
  <p id="Results">Pie is 0 / 8 (0%) Complete.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pieSlice {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 75px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*transform:rotate(50deg);*/
}

svg {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px 37px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

circle {
  fill: white;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 75;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 239;
}

#NewSlice {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

#MakePie {
  width: 225px;
  height: 225px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  background: white;
}

#NewSlice p,
#MakePie p {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
var myPie = 0;
var pieTotal = 8;
var c = 239; //2*pi*r
var arc = 30; // c / number of slices (8)

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#NewSlice div.draggable").draggable({
    opacity: 0.7,
    helper: "clone"
  });
  $("#MakePie").droppable({
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(e, i) {
      console.log("Slice dropped on Pie.");
      if (myPie < pieTotal) {
        myPie++;
        $("#Results").html("Pie is " + myPie + " / " + pieTotal + " (" + ((myPie / pieTotal) * 100) + "%) Complete.");
        $("circle").css("stroke-dasharray", (arc * myPie) + " 239");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Drag a slice onto the pizza pie area and a 1/8 slice is drawn using the Stroke Dash method. Grow the dash as more slices are added. Again you could do similar in Canvas. Clone a slice into the circle. Clone a second, rotate it etc.